# Selenium Firefox Preference for opening downloaded files

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I've been looking for a way to download and run a JNLP file when using Selenium and Firefox. In the Firefox browser, I have the setting as shown in the screenshot below, so that the JNLP file downloads and runs without any popups.

[image]

Is it possible to replicate this is with FireFox Profile? I have the following set up, but it only downloads the file, it isn't automatically opening the file:

```
void setFireFoxDriverProperty(){
    
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\TestAutomation\\selenium_drivers\\geckodriver.exe")

    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile()
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false)
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "c:\\temp")
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-java-jnlp-file")
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/x-java-jnlp-file")

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions()
    options.setProfile(profile)
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system("javaws C:\\Users\\gkarthic\\Desktop\\Final\\latest\\your_jnlp_file.jnlp")
```

use `javaws` command and use your jnlp file path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).